# Xtext ServerLauncher not running while trying to generate a language server

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, language-server-protocol

I am using Eclipse DSL package 2020-09 with Amazon Corette java 11. I followed the instructions mentioned in https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/340_lsp_support.html for generating a sample language server. However while running the java application using a xtext ServerLauncher (org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.ServerLauncher), I just get some warnings and no further information is available. There is no server created as well. Nothing is there in eclipse logs too. What am I missing here?

Console output:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/C:/Users/yellared/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the warning is unrelated. what do you mean by "There is no server created as well."

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused by that first cause I assumed that launching the server would also spawn a second eclipse instance. It does not do that, the server is launched successfully (as Christian points out, the warning is unrelated).

You can add a "General Project" directly to your development eclipse instance:

General Project from New.. Wizard
[image: General Project from New.. Wizard]

There, you can add a new text file with your DSLs extension. Make sure that you have defined a **Content Type** for your language extension and assigned it to server launcher, as explained in the [Xtext documentation, step 3](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/340_lsp_support.html).

Comment: [It would be preferable](//stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of defining the Content Type in the text file, and provide the link for attribution. At the moment, if the link changes then future readers may not know what to do